# How to use local env vars in docker-compose

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I want to pass user id and group id to my docker-compose.yml. I tried to do that in several ways and the only way it works is when I export the variables and then call `docker-compose up` for example.

```
export USER_ID="$(id -u)"
export GROUP_ID="$(getent group devs | cut -d: -f3)"
docker-compose up
```

Or when I edit the ~/.bash_profile which is not ideal.

This is not something I want as **I want the end user to only run `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose --env-file .env up` and get the service running.**

I would try do achieve this with `.env` file but I can't use stuff like this in .env like I did earlier and I need those variables exported.

`GROUP_ID="$(getent group devs | cut -d: -f3)"` I get nothing if I write something like this in .env file.

In my `docker-compose.yml` I have this:

```
environment:
  USER_ID: $(USER_ID)
  GROUP_ID: $(GROUP_ID)
env_file:
  .env
```

And in .env

```
USER_ID="$(id -u)"
GROUP_ID="$(getent group devs | cut -d: -f3)"
```

I know it makes no sense. I can do something like

```
USER_ID=1000
GROUP_ID=117
```

But those values are not supposed to be fixed as they change depending on the user.
How can I assign the output of a Linux command to env variable in .env? And how to use that in my docker-compose?

Comment: end users are not running docker compose up. Apart from that there should be few occasions where this thing with the uid is required, and this would be for development when working with certain bind mounts. Anyway you can use direnv and a .envrc https://direnv.net/

Comment: Development involves installing packages, otherwise how do you develop?  I would also expect devs to be able to export their uid and gid, if someone of the dev team cannot do that, they might have picked the wrong job. Just documented it and set some reasonable default with is 1000 for both. Should cover 90% of devs without having to touch it. btw uid is already in a variable `echo $UID`. Not sure if there is one for gid.

Comment: I tried to edit the comment and I deleted it. Sorry. Yes, I agree with you, unfortunately I'm not the one making decisions. I found the solution which works, it's basically just running two export commands and then `docker-compose up`, no need for .env files,  but they don't accept the solution since they have to run something else besides `docker-compose up`.  @TheFool

Comment: tell them to export these variables one time in their .profile and forget about it. They will be available in every session they start. As it stands, you cannot solve this with the requirements you describe. You need to do *something*. Compose won't pick up the uid:gid automatically, that's just the way it is.